# Using std::vector<> and std::shared_ptr<> should cause error

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, c++14

Here is my code of what I am doing :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> ar = {1};

  shared_ptr<int> sp(&ar[0]);

  cout<<*sp<<endl; // ---- [1]

  ar[0] = 10;

  cout<<*sp<<endl; // ---- [2]

  ar.clear();

  cout<<*sp<<endl; // ---- [3]



  return 0;
}
```

The output is coming to be :

```
1
10
10
```

Instead of `cout` at `[3]` I think, there should be any error at runtime, since the the object to be accessed is already deleted. How it is printing `10` in `[3]`? Or should I use any `g++` flag, I am just using `g++ -std=c++14 a1.cpp && ./a.out`

EDIT: On running on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9bd8f2c65925aa4) I found out that `clang++` is giving

```
`*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption (fasttop):     0x0000000002138010 ***`
```

But `g++` is not [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bb5ea91ca1d668d).

Comment: Is it not crashing when it reaches the end of `main`?

Comment: @DavidRodriguez-dribeas no not even crashing, just exiting like nothing happened!

Comment: clearing a vector doesn't mean necessarily that its allocated memory is being deleted.

Comment: Very similar question, though not exactly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, and undefined behaviour is undefined. It may crash, or it may not. All you are doing is accessing memory you shouldn't, its not supposed to be done, but its not necessarily fatal.

Comment: Where do people get this idea that writing bad C++ code means you are guaranteed to get a crash?

Comment: @JonathanWakely When asked what an invalid access causes, many people answer just by "it'll crash". Because they fear the "oh, if it just does nothing it's fine then" reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much bypassing anything that would guarantee a run-time error when you try to access outside the current bounds of the vector.

If you want the bounds checked, you might consider something like this instead:

```
std::vector<int> ar { 1 };

std::cout << ar.at(0); // no problem

ar.clear();

std::cout << ar.at(0); // guaranteed to throw an exception
```

A `shared_ptr` is for *shared* ownership of an object, so the object will be deleted only when there's nothing left to own it. By contrast, a `std::vector` assumes *sole* ownership of all the objects it contains, so trying to refer to one of them with a `shared_ptr` leads only to problems.

On the other hand, the fact that with gcc this manages to exit without a (visible) sign of the problem doesn't technically qualify as a bug in the compiler. At the end of the scope, the `shared_ptr` and the `std::vector` will both attempt to free the `int` to which the `shared_ptr` refers--but there's no requirement that doing so leads to an error message (officially that's a quality of implementation issue, though I'd certainly agree that showing the message is better than not).

Answer (score 1):

It is an undefined behavior. It may  or may not print 10.

`std::vector::clear()` deleted the object and reallocation is not guaranteed. So system may not reuse that memory, so you may get old value as result if you access the same memory location.

There is an interesting observation, if you check `std::shared_ptr::use_cout()` after `std::vector::clear()` operation, you could see answer 1.

```
  vector<int> ar = {1};

  shared_ptr<int> sp(&ar[0]);

  cout<<*sp<<"\n"; // ---- [1]

  ar[0] = 10;

  cout<<*sp<<"\n"; // ---- [2]

  ar.clear();
  cout<< sp.use_count()<<"\n";

  cout<<*sp<<endl; // ---- [3]
```

Output

```
1
10
1
10
```

Comment: `std::vector<>::clear()` does not deallocate, it is still memory managed by the vector. Still, it is undefined behavior as the object is *not there* anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code. The most obvious one is that you are creating a `shared_ptr` to manage an object that is already managed by the `vector` and will most probably get a double delete at the end of `main`.

The other problem is that you have a pointer to an object and use it after the object has been *removed*, since `std::vector<int>::clear` does not deallocate the memory you are hitting memory that is still managed by the vector and that's why it does not explode, but the object is not there any more, and you should not be accessing it. If instead of a `int` it had been a `std::string` the program may have crashed (it may also not have crashed, that is the nature of undefined behavior)

Comment: Yeah, my program `crashed` with `std::string`. :)